# How to manipulate filestream in memory before uploading

Tags: javascript, azure, fine-uploader, fileapi

I'm working on an uploader that needs to censor a few bytes in the uploaded data by overwriting them to a predetermined value, before uploading them.

Right now, I've hooked into the `onSubmit` event because it allows for non-blocking work to be performed. Below you can see my event handler. Just before the call to `promise.success();` you will note the heavily commented part, which is the problem I need help with. How can I return/set the byte array there?

```
onSubmit: function (id, name) {
    // http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#submit
    // Called when the item has been selected and is a candidate for uploading.
    // Return false to prevent submission to the uploader.

    // create promise
    var promise = new qq.Promise();

    // configure file reader
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onerror = function (e) {
        promise.failure("error occured reading file");
    };
    reader.onabort = function (e) {
        promise.failure("file reading aborted");
    };
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        var buffer = reader.result;
        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(buffer);

        manipulateByteArray(byteArray);

        /******************* Missing part... **********************/
        // TODO (How to return manipulated byteArray?)
        /******************* Missing part...**********************/

        // signal success
        promise.success();
    }

    // initiate async work
    var file = this.getFile(id);
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

    // return promise
    return promise;
},
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the question, or your code. It's not clear what you want to do with byte arrays, or what you mean by "censor a few bytes". You cannot change the contents of a `File` or `Blob` object. You can only create a new one and upload that.

Comment: Doing exactly that solved my problems. See the revised code below. Thanks again for the useful suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. This was the crucial part:

```
        if(needsManipulation(byteArray))
        {
            manipulateByteArray(byteArray);

            // construct a new blob
            var newBlob = { blob: new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/octet-stream' }), name: name };

            // restart the process for the adjusted file
            uploader.addFiles(newBlob);

            // signal failure and exit early
            promise.failure();
            return;
        }
```

Here's the revised code:

```
onSubmit: function (id, name) {
    // http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#submit
    // Called when the item has been selected and is a candidate for uploading.
    // Return false to prevent submission to the uploader.

    // create promise
    var promise = new qq.Promise();

    // add uploader instance to closure
    var uploader = this;

    // configure file reader
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onerror = function (e) {
        promise.failure("error occured reading file");
    };
    reader.onabort = function (e) {
        promise.failure("file reading aborted");
    };
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        var buffer = reader.result;
        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(buffer);

        if(needsManipulation(byteArray))
        {
            manipulateByteArray(byteArray);

            // construct a new blob
            var newBlob = { blob: new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/octet-stream' }), name: name };

            // restart the process for the adjusted file
            uploader.addFiles(newBlob);

            // signal failure and exit early
            promise.failure();
            return;
        }

        // signal success
        promise.success();
    }

    // initiate async reading work
    var file = this.getFile(id);
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

    // return promise
    return promise;
},
```

Comment: Note that you do not need to encase the blob in an array, you can simply call `uploader.addFiles(newBlob)`.

Comment: Just want to add that you don't have to use Fine Uploader's internal "Promise" module (it's not spec-compliant at all). You can use any promise library you desire.

Comment: Since the app hardly uses javascript otherwise, there is no other library available. I was glad that you included one in FineUploader because it saved me another library!

Comment: Yes, I created that naïve implementation before the promise spec existed (or at least before I had knowledge of it). So keep in mind that the behaviors and methods of Fine Uploader's internal promise impl are non-standard. I'll probably never fix this since the changes would need to be breaking ones and I made changes at some point that allow use of _any_ compliant promise library instead.

Comment: I've solved the issue and have clarified the code in this question/answer for others to read, I'll accept my answer tomorrow. Thanks.